# siteId 16617 not returning expected results with jsonsdk/DataService/getItemSummariesForSite API

Tags: yodlee

I am following the [pattern described in the manual](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Quickstart/Aggregation_REST_Quick_Start_Guide).

Specifically, at step 5 when a user supplies incorrect credentials, step 6 should return feedback specifying bad user credentials.

I am calling jsonsdk/SiteAccountManagement/addSiteAccount1 with the following params:

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'enclosedType' => 'com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle',
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'credentialFields.enclosedType' => 'com.yodlee.common.FieldInfoSingle',
    'siteId' => '16617',
    'credentialFields[0].valueIdentifier' => 'LOGIN',
    'credentialFields[0].valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
    'credentialFields[0].fieldType.typeName' => 'IF_LOGIN',
    'credentialFields[0].size' => '19',
    'credentialFields[0].name' => 'LOGIN',
    'credentialFields[0].displayName' => 'Card/Access Number',
    'credentialFields[0].isEditable' => 'true',
    'credentialFields[0].value' => 'BAD', 
    'credentialFields[1].valueIdentifier' => 'PASSWORD',
    'credentialFields[1].valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
    'credentialFields[1].fieldType.typeName' => 'IF_PASSWORD',
    'credentialFields[1].size' => '7',
    'credentialFields[1].name' => 'PASSWORD',
    'credentialFields[1].displayName' => 'Security Number',
    'credentialFields[1].isEditable' => 'true',
    'credentialFields[1].value' => 'BAD', 
    'credentialFields[2].valueIdentifier' => 'PASSWORD1',
    'credentialFields[2].valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
    'credentialFields[2].fieldType.typeName' => 'IF_PASSWORD',
    'credentialFields[2].size' => '12',
    'credentialFields[2].name' => 'PASSWORD1',
    'credentialFields[2].displayName' => 'Internet Password',
    'credentialFields[2].isEditable' => 'true',
    'credentialFields[2].value' => 'BAD', 
    'credentialFields[3].valueIdentifier' => 'OPTION',
    'credentialFields[3].valueMask' => 'LOGIN_FIELD',
    'credentialFields[3].fieldType.typeName' => 'OPTIONS',
    'credentialFields[3].size' => '20',
    'credentialFields[3].name' => 'OPTION',
    'credentialFields[3].displayName' => 'Issue Number ',
    'credentialFields[3].isEditable' => 'true',
    'credentialFields[3].value' => '2',
)
```

It is returning:

```
array (
    'siteAccountId' => 10381802,
    'isCustom' => false, 
    'credentialsChangedTime' => 1412058909,
    'siteRefreshInfo' => 
    array (
        'siteRefreshStatus' => 
        array (
            'siteRefreshStatusId' => 1,
            'siteRefreshStatus' => 'REFRESH_TRIGGERED',
        ),
        'siteRefreshMode' => 
        array (
            'refreshModeId' => 2,
            'refreshMode' => 'NORMAL',
        ),
        'updateInitTime' => 1412058909,
        'nextUpdate' => 1412059809,
        'code' => 801,
        'suggestedFlow' => 
        array (
            'suggestedFlowId' => 2,
            'suggestedFlow' => 'REFRESH',
        ),
        'noOfRetry' => 0,
    ),
    'siteInfo' =>
    array (
        'popularity' => 0,
        'siteId' => 16617,
        'orgId' => 9006,
        'defaultDisplayName' => 'Bank of Melbourne (Australia)',
        'defaultOrgDisplayName' => 'Bank of Melbourne',
        'enabledContainers' =>
        array (
            0 =>
            array (
                'containerName' => 'bills',
                'assetType' => 0,
            ),
        ),
        'baseUrl' => 'http://www.bankofmelbourne.com.au/',
        'loginForms' =>
        array (
        ),
        'isHeld' => false,
        'isCustom' => false,
        'siteSearchVisibility' => true,
    ),
    'created' => '2014-09-29T23:35:09-0700',
    'retryCount' => 0,
)
```

I am then extracting the 'siteAccountId' field and expect to eventually receive a notification of the bad credentials.

Here is a log of the consecutive calls to jsonsdk/DataService/getItemSummariesForSite, the responses and timestamps.

Attempt 1 Sent(2014-09-30 17:21:23):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 1 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 2 Sent(2014-09-30 17:21:34):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 2 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 3 Sent(2014-09-30 17:21:55):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 3 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 4 Sent(2014-09-30 17:22:16):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 4 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 5 Sent(2014-09-30 17:22:38):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 5 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 6 Sent(2014-09-30 17:22:59):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 6 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 7 Sent(2014-09-30 17:23:20):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 7 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 8 Sent(2014-09-30 17:23:41):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 8 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 9 Sent(2014-09-30 17:24:02):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 9 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 10 Sent(2014-09-30 17:24:23):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 10 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 11 Sent(2014-09-30 17:24:44):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 11 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 12 Sent(2014-09-30 17:25:06):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 12 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 13 Sent(2014-09-30 17:25:27):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 13 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

Attempt 14 Sent(2014-09-30 17:25:48):

```
array (
    'cobSessionToken' => 'REDACTED',
    'memSiteAccId' => 10381802,
    'userSessionToken' => 'REDACTED'
```

)

Attempt 14 Received:

```
array (
    'key' =>
    array (
    ),
)
```

For other siteId's I can rely on receiving one of the following attributes:

- ['refreshInfo']['itemAccessStatus']['name'] == 'ACCESS_NOT_VERIFIED'
- ['refreshInfo']['userActionRequiredType']['name'] == 'CHANGE_CREDENTIALS'

Can a yodlee staffer please check their logs and investigate why siteId 16617 is not returning the expected data when using jsonsdk/DataService/getItemSummariesForSite

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement the complete add account flow indicated in this page of [Add_Site_Account](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/API_Flow/Add_Site_Account) flow.

Please follow the flow diagram and code accordingly. Ideally you should call [getSiteRefreshInfo](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getSiteRefreshInfo) to know the status of refresh of the account which you tried adding.

Comment: We have implemented the suggested workflow and it has not resolved our issue.

We have more information on the cause, which should be escalated to the appropriate Yodlee engineers.

Calls to getSiteRefeshInfo are returning code 403, which according to the [Yodlee Error codes][1] is a fatal Agent Error.

Can we have an engineer investigate and either provide a workaround or a timeline when the 403 error can be resolved.


  [1]: https://developer.yodlee.com/FAQs/Error_Codes

Comment: Since you are a customer to Yodlee, please file a service request using Yodlee customer care tool and provide the siteAccountID and cobrandID